# Update Redux Store

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to update the redux store but when I try to access both points and sessionId, they come back undefined. I am sure there is a problem with my reducer, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my reducer:

```
import { UPDATE_POINTS, SET_SESSION } from '../path'

const initialState = {
    sessionId: null,
    points: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POINTS:
            return {
                points: action.points
            }
        case SET_SESSION:
            return {
                sessionId: action.session
            }
        default:
            return state;
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

Action Creators

```
export function updatePoints(points){
    return {
        type: UPDATE_POINTS,
        points
    }
}

export function setSession(session){
    return {
        type: SET_SESSION,
        session
    }
}
```

Within React Component (for simplicity I took most everything else out of this function)

```
handleSelect(e) {
    this.props.setSession(e);
    console.log(this.props.sessionId);
}
```

This function is used when a menu item is chosen from a drop down menu. On the first selection, the console shows whatever is in the initial state for sessionId. Any further drop down selections result in undefined in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close. A reducer in redux needs to return the *a new copy of the entire state*. Your reducer is returning only the key it's concerned with, which is going to drop the other key. You need to return a new copy of the state with your key updated. For example:

```
const initialState = {
  sessionId: null,
  points: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action = null) => {
  // Exit early if you don't have an action (returning old state) 
  if (!action) return state;

  // This function will assign your patch onto the old state, and then 
  // assign all of that onto a NEW object. For redux to do it's job,
  // you can't modulate the old object, you have to return a new one.
  const update = patch => Object.assign({}, state, patch);

  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_POINTS:
      return update({
        points: action.points
      });

    case SET_SESSION:
      return update({
        sessionId: action.session
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And for the record, instead of putting your data payload under a unique key each time in your action creators, if you put the payload under a `data` key then your action will follow the standard flux action format.

```
export const updatePoints = (points) => ({
  type: UPDATE_POINTS,
  data: points
});

export const setSession = (session) => ({
  type: SET_SESSION,
  data: session
});
```

There you go. Good luck, and if you get stuck, refer back to the Redux docs (they're really good). [Link to Redux Docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)